# MVC: Populate a <select> from SQL Server database

Tags: html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, post

I have the below example html select (dropdown)

```
<select name="Testing">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
<option value="3">Option 3</option>
<option value="4" selected>Select</option>
</select>
```

And the following SQL Server Table:

```
ID NAME
1  Apple
2  Orange
3  Peach
```

This drop down is part of a form which is posted to server, the value is read using:

```
reqparm.Add("TestDropdown", Request["Testing"].ToString());
```

How do I populate the drop down while keeping the name attribute?

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Comment: http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/dropdownlist-helper-data-binding-in-mvc.html

Comment: Thanks for the responce, I haven't tried any solution yet Arijit as i dont have one to test yet, but I don't think I can use dropdownlist or dropdownlistfor because they have no name property which would break the http post to server.

Comment: Dropdownlist have Text and Value property
Text will be treated as Name and Id as Value

Answer (score 2):

In the end the solution I produced avoided the html helpers (personally don't like them)

In your index method of home controller:

```
// create list of my viewmodel policyorg equals my db table in a list

List<PolicyOrganisation> policyOrgs = db.PolicyOrganisations.ToList();

// pass results to viewbag

ViewBag.PolicyOrgs = policyOrgs;
```

then in Index.cshtml

```
// Loop throught items in viewbag and add each to the select

<select id="DD1" name="PolicyOrganisation">
                        <option value="-1">Select</option>    
                        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.PolicyOrgs)
                        {
                            <option value="@item.Id">@item.Name</option>
                        }
                    </select>
```